# Question about prime factorization of remainders

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic

If $x$ mod $m$ = $y$, and we know the prime factorizations of $x$ and $m$, does this tell us anything about $y$?

Comment: It's incorrect to say "$x\pmod m=\ldots$"  What you mean is $x-m\lfloor\frac xm\rfloor$

Comment: Actually, we may consider [mod](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation) to be a unary function, via precisely your definition.

Comment: Are you assuming $0\leq y\leq m-1$? In any case, if $x$ and $y$ have the same residue modulo $m$, you know that $x=y+km$ for some integer $k$, which is an **additive** relationship. And therefore, I don't think you can get the prime factorization of $y$, since this has to do with **multiplication** of integers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We know that $\gcd(x,m)=\gcd(y,m)$, and very little more.

- We do know a *little bit* more.  Let $d=\gcd(x,m)$, $x=dx', m=dm'$, with $\gcd(x',m')=1$.
  Since $m|(x-y)$, we also know that $d|(x-y)$ but also $m'|(x-y)$.  Hence if we write $y=dy'$, then we know that $y'\equiv x'\pmod{m'}$.  The primes dividing $y'$ may be entirely different from those primes dividing $x'$, however their product gives the same residue modulo $m'$.